# Using ? and : operators compared to { and }

Tags: php

I have seen in many situations on Stack overflow, I see people using examples containing:

```
$Var = isset($_SESSION['Key'])? $_SESSION['Key']: null;
```

What is the actual structure and representation? is there any performance improvements server sided with using these operators compared to a simple `if` and `else` statement?  or is this generally down to personal programming preference?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: I'd be suprised if there was any performance difference. It's perfect for setting default values to variables, but it remains a matter of preference.

Comment: Personal preference, concise code, clarity of variable assignments.  It's called the _ternary operator_

Comment: Yes, the manual is clear; but it does not specify performance hits, best practices etc.

Comment: So it's mainly preference?

Comment: keep in mind, this is a high level langague, and its likely that the actual code executed via if-else vs ? is identical after compilation. I personally like being able to present that kind of operation as  one line, as it makes clear that one thing is being done.

Comment: I'm not sure about PHP specifically, but couldn't this become a conditional move instead of a jump possibly after compilation?

Answer (score 1):

It is just to produce shorter code. It is equivalent to:

```
if (someCondition) // do if true
else // do otherwise
```

or for your code...

```
if ($_SESSION['Key']) $Var = $_SESSION['Key'];
else $Var = null;
```